# What happens if you don't close a filehandle in Perl?

Tags: perl, stdout, stderr, read-write, filehandler

If I am writing a Perl script that overwrites STDERR with a duplicate of STDOUT but I never restore the filehandle, what happens at the end of script execution? I can't find anything that warns against what actually occurs or doesn't occur.

I'm probably misinformed but thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When a process exits, the kernel recovers all used resources. This includes all the file descriptors, which are simply closed. If there is an application-level buffer, data in that buffer may not have been written to the kernel, but otherwise there is no risk in keeping file descriptors open before exiting.

If your Perl script ends by using `exec` to launch another process, that process will inherit all the file descriptors (except those marked as close on exec).

Comment: Also, perl will normally take care of flushing its own buffers as needed, unless you do something silly like `kill 9, $$`.  Although it appears that there are some minor [remaining issues with that](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#exec) on a few platforms.